# Dual boot Windows 10 & Ubuntu 16.04 -- blank purple screen of death when booting Windows!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

This is on my Dell XPS 9550 laptop with 512GB Samsung P951 NVMe SSD. I first installed Windows 10 and it boot up just fine. Then I shrinked the volume for Ubuntu and installed it via Live USB ("Something else" method). Once successfully installed, I booted into Ubuntu just fine. If I choose Windows 10 from the grub menu, I get an infinite blank purple screen. However, I know Windows loaded because if I put a USB in the port, I can hear a chime indicating it is inserted. Now, if I push the power button, it goes to sleep. Pushing it again brings me back to the grub menu, where I choose Windows option, and it resumes to the desktop fine--I assume it is resuming. I don't want to have to do the following steps to make it go away.

Any ideas what went wrong, or where to troubleshoot?

Comment: Can you boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, f12, not grub menu? You may have left Windows fast start up on, or Windows needs chkdsk. Or you have secure boot on. Grub will not boot Windows in any of those cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Windows startup repair cd for Windows 10.Then used it to solve this problem.This already happen to me , I solved this using this method